# RestApi: 404, 422 or 500?

Tags: http, http-error

Lets assume we have two objects. `post` and `comment`. `post` has n-`comment`s.

If I want to get (or change) a `comment` of a `post` then I can also do an
`[DELETE, GET, PATCH] posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}`
instead of
`[DELETE, GET, PATCH] GET comments/{commentId}`

But ... what is when the server notice, that the given `commentId` exits, but has a other `postId` as the client-request says? Is that a ...

1. 404 (not found) - because the complete path not exsits.
2. 422 (unprocessable entity) - because syntax is right, but the semantics are not.
3. 500 (internal server error) - because its a unexpected condition  see (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500).

Comment: What do you want to tell me @Ivar?

Comment: In this case it doesnt matter - I also can do a `DELETE posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}`. The error code should be the same, or not?

Comment: Is that better for you?

Comment: Yep. And not just for me, but also to future visitors of this question who might not be aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely a *client error*, so the proper status code should be in the [`4xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) range.

---

When a resource representation cannot be found for a given URI, then the server is expected to return a response with the [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) status code:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. [...]

---

The [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) status code is meant to indicate a payload that is *syntactically valid* but is *semantically invalid*.

Consider, for example, you have an endpoint to create comments and the payload should contain the identifier of the post which this comment belongs to:

```
POST /comments HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "content": "Awesome post!",
  "postId": 1
}
```

In this situation, if `postId` refers to a post that doesn't exist, the server should return [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2).